Prove congruences involving sums of powers modulo a prime
Let $p > 5$ be a prime number.
For $k \in \{1, \cdots, p-1\}$, we define $\frac{1}{k} \equiv [x_k] \pmod{p}$, where $x_k$ satisfies $x_k \cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. For $k \in \{1, \cdots, p-1\}$, we define $\frac{1}{k} \equiv [x_k] \pmod{p^2}$, where $x_k$ satisfies $x_k \cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod{p^2}$.
Actually they are definition of inversion under $\pmod{p}$ and $\pmod{p^2}$.
Prove the following congruences:
(1) $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{k^4} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$
(2) $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{k^3} \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$
I have a solution for the first question. First, note that $1, 2, \ldots, p-1$ and $1^{-1}, 2^{-1}, \ldots, (p-1)^{-1}$ form the same set of residues modulo $p$.
Therefore,
$1^4 + 2^4 + \ldots + (p-1)^4 \equiv 1^{-4} + 2^{-4} + \ldots + (p-1)^{-4} \pmod{p}$
Then, using the corollary to Wolstenholme's theorem from this source, we know that when $p-1$ does not divide 4,
$1^4 + 2^4 + \ldots + (p-1)^4 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$
This proves the first part of the question.
Is this approach valid? Additionally, how should I approach the second part of the question?
edit: I just got some hint from others. In order to prove the second part, I should first multiply the left hand side by 2. But I can't figure out what to do next.
edit:I have figured out a solution of the second part. Is this solution correct?

By Euler's theorem, for any $1 \leq k \leq p-1$:
$k^{p^2-p-3} \equiv k^{-3} \pmod{p^2}$
Consider $2\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{-3}$, pairing $k$ with $p-k$:
$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} [k^{p^2-p-3} + (p-k)^{p^2-p-3}] \pmod{p^2}$
Binomial expansion yields:
$k^{p^2-p-3} + (p-k)^{p^2-p-3} \equiv (p^2-p-3)pk^{p^2-p-4} \pmod{p^2}$
Therefore, the original sum is equivalent to:
$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} (p^2-p-3)pk^{p^2-p-4} \pmod{p^2}$
$\equiv p(p^2-p-3)\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{p^2-p-4} \pmod{p^2}$
By the result from Math Garden Blog, power sums are 0 $\pmod{p}$ when the exponent is not divisible by $p-1$.
Verify $p^2-p-4 \equiv -4 \pmod{p-1}$, which is not divisible by $p-1$ when $p > 5$.
Thus the proposition is proved.


No need of Wolstenholm for (1): simply use that $$S:=1^4 + 2^4 + 3^4 + \cdots + n^4= {n(n+1)(2n+1)(3n^2+3n-1) \over 30},$$ hence $n+1\mid30S$.

Is there a typo?  You have two different definitions of $\frac 1k.$

@non-euclideangeometry There are 2 definitions, one for $ \frac{1}{k} \pmod{p}$ and one for $ \frac{1}{k} \pmod{p^2}$. If it helps, think of them as 2 distinct questions.
